# Converting \n to <br/>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problem converting \n to a < br / >

```js
function format() {
  var text = document.getElementById("formatArea").value;
  text.replace("\n", "<br/>");
  document.getElementById("resultArea").value = text;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="formatArea">
</textarea>


<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="resultArea">
</textarea>

<button onclick="format()">Click to create HTML breaks</button>
```

Appreciate any help, i'm not very experienced in JS yet.

Comment: If you put a string in the first parameter of `replace`, it will only replace the first occurence. If you want to replace them all, use a Regular Expression. For your usecase, it should be : `text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");`

Comment: @Seblor you should probably copy your comment into an answer since it looks valid. (Update: seems like you did! upvoting your answer)

Comment: Yep, gotta set the global flag. Seblor, submit as answer.

Comment: Totally upvoting too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

Firstly, `replace` does not change the original string, it returns a modified string. (Documentation link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Secondly, if you put a string in the first parameter of replace, it will only replace the first occurence. If you want to replace them all, use a Regular Expression.

So you should have this :

```
function format() {
  var text = document.getElementById("formatArea").value;
  text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
  document.getElementById("resultArea").value = text;
}
```

The `g` ("global") flag on a regular expression is used to match all occurences.

Answer (score 0):

*Replace all* was something I didn't understand when I started learning JavaScript too!

**TL;DR** There isn't a `replaceAll` function in JavaScript. But `replace` accepts something called *regular expressions*.

To replace all `foo`s with `bar`s in a string you have to do `.replace(/foo/g, "bar")`. `/foo/g` will match all the `"foo"`s and will replace them with bar. `g` is called *flag* and it it means *global*, meaning you match them all.

If you want to replace `\n`s you have to do: `.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")`, like we did for `foo`:

```
text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")
```

Also, you have to *assign* the new string to the old string, as `replace` would not modify the original variable value:

```js
function format() {
  var text = document.getElementById("formatArea").value;
  text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
  document.getElementById("resultArea").value = text;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="formatArea">
</textarea>


<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="resultArea">
</textarea>

<button onclick="format()">Click to create HTML breaks</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/\n/g` for global replace and you have also missed the assignment of the changed `text` value in `text` itself, thus the replaced text was not taking effect. You need to assign the replaced value like `text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");` :

```js
function format() {
    var text = document.getElementById("formatArea").value;
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
    document.getElementById("resultArea").value = text;
}
```

```css
asd
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="formatArea">
</textarea>


<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="resultArea">
</textarea>

<button onclick="format()">Click to create HTML breaks</button>
```